# PHP Array Map & Join in Wolf CMS

Tags: php

I'm attempting to add a set of data to a div's data attribute like so:

```
<div data-foo="<?php echo join(",", array_map(function($video){return $video->title();}, $videos)); ?>"></div>
```

But it fails at this line. However I have been able to verify that the array of videos do have titles. For example, this works:

```
<?php echo current($videos)->title(); ?>
```

I verified with an online PHP validator that there isn't a syntax issue, but I'm new to both PHP and Wolf CMS, so I'm not certain where it's failing or even how to properly debug it.

The desired output would be:

```
<div data-foo="84726530,84726614,84726779,84726915"></div>
```

Comment: `But it fails at this line` What exactely fails?

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat The output ceases to be rendered. Basically if I leave that whole line  out, the page and the pieces all render aside from this piece of data. But if it's in then the entire section of the page that houses this (which happens within a foreach loop) renders nothing.

Comment: Code seems to be okay for me. Just tested it locally (and mocked the Video Object) and it ran fine. Enable error reporting or take a look at your error log and see what error you receive and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it didn't like the anonymous function. Changing it to a named method fixed it.

```
<?php function callback($video){return $video->title();} ?>

<div data-foo="<?php echo join(",", array_map("callback", $videos)); ?>"></div>
```

Is this a version of PHP issue? Or does Wolf CMS limit things somehow? I have no idea, but at least it's working now.